# Best way to restore individual folders via Time Machine after clean Lion install?

Tags: osx-lion, time-machine

I'm doing a clean erase and install of Lion, and am looking for the best way to restore individual folders into my home directory via Time Machine.

I've done a dummy run, clean Lion install, then 'browse other disks' in Time Machine, navigate to my home folder and 'restore' what I need, such as pictures/music and folders inside the .library folder (such as Mail and Keychains). However this method seems to give you odd permissions, like this:

[image]

Hence I wondered if anyone knows what the best method is to restore files and folders after a clean install.

N.b I do not want to use the migration assistant, or 'restore OS from Time Machine' - as I specifically want to do a clean install, and just copy over what I need (some folders will be moved onto a separate disk to the OS, and some will remain on the same disk).

Answer (score 0):

I used the exact same method you describe to transfer files to my grandparents new computer after their old one died. However, I didn't think to check the permissions. (They haven't complained yet, so hopefully nothing bad has happened.) However, if you are worried about the permissions, try using Disk Utility to repair permissions. (I don't think this will work, because I think Disk Utility only repairs permissions of apps installed with an installer, but it's worth a try.) I personally would find out what the permissions are supposed to be, then use terminal to change them to what they need to be. You should be able to change whole directories with `chmod -R`. (Be careful, because you could end up removing executable permissions from executables if they are hiding some where in the directory you change.)